# bezierPathWithRoundedRect not perfect circle

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-graphics, geometry

I have some problem with draw circle:

This simply code demonstrates that:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    self.layer.sublayers = nil;
    CGFloat radius = self.frame.size.width/2;

    circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.width) cornerRadius:radius].CGPath;

    circle.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    circle.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

    circle.lineWidth = 4;

    [self.layer addSublayer:circle];

    CABasicAnimation *drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];

    drawAnimation.duration            = 1.0; // "animate over 10 seconds or so.."
    drawAnimation.repeatCount         = 1.0;  // Animate only once..

    drawAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    drawAnimation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1];

    drawAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    drawAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

    drawAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

    drawAnimation.delegate = self;
    [circle addAnimation:drawAnimation forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];

}
```

And we have result

[image]
First three circles draws by method above, last circle I draw in PS.
If u can see bezierPathWithRoundedRect draws not perfect circle with right radius I think (some corners added to circle). How to draw circle like last circle in a picture?

PS: I need to use bezierPathWithArcCenter for my project, but when I reuse bezierPathWithRoundedRect I has same problem!

Comment: A rounded rect is a rectangle with rounded corners. A circle is a circle. If you want a circle, draw a circle.

Comment: To add a bit of context. Mathematically speaking Bézier curves are weighted summations of parametric cubic polynomials. They are extremely versatile but they will not give identical results to primitive shapes. Also, don't down vote this; it's a good question.

Comment: Why add this here? Ask as a different question. And make this one as answered.

Comment: @boyfarrell u are right, but not answer, bezierPathWithOvalInRect = results is same

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `+ (NSBezierPath *)bezierPathWithOvalInRect:(NSRect)aRect` for a circle.

By definition a RoundedRect is squarish.

Comment: bezierPathWithOvalInRect is have same problem, pls check!

Answer (score 0):

To draw circles you need to use arcs.

Look at [appendBezierPathWithArcFromPoint:toPoint:radius:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBezierPath_Class/%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBezierPath/appendBezierPathWithArcFromPoint:toPoint:radius:)

[Ovals are not ellipses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oval%23Technical_drawing) (although they are commonly used interchangeably in English). Ellipse is a generalise circle.

Answer (score 0):

The best result I found was to use `CGContextAddEllipseInRect:` in `drawRect:`

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect boundingRect = CGRectMake(2.0f, 2.0f, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds)-4.0, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds)-4.0);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, boundingRect);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```